# passing event and prop to a function of a react js component

Tags: reactjs

I have an App component that has another (Person) component in it that passes some data (status) that goes to a function, which is supposed to validate its value to the text value of another two button components (depending on which one is clicked) inside the App component. I need to give those buttons a value that can then be passed on as a parameter to the validation function, how is this achieved in react?

App

```js
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Person from "./Person";
import Feedback from "./Feedback";
import Score from "./Score";

function App() {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  function statusCheck(personStatus) {
    //checks if the button pressed
    //matches the persons' status from <Person> component
    console.log(personStatus);
  }

  function updateScore() {
    //keeps track and updates the score based on user input (buttons)

    setScore((prev) => prev + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="Main">
      <div className="Stats">
        <Score score={score} className="Score"></Score>
        <Feedback className="Feedback"></Feedback>
      </div>

      <Person className="Person" personStatus={statusCheck}></Person>

      <div className="Buttons">
        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
          <Button onClick={statusCheck} variant="contained">
            Dead
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={statusCheck} variant="contained">
            Ugly
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Person

```js
import "./App.css";
import data from "./data.json";

//var num = data.length();

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function Person({ personStatus }) {
  var length = data.length - 1; //data.length - 1;
  personStatus(data[length].status);
  //console.log(`number of people in json data file: ${length + 1}`);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <img id="Photo" src={data[length].img}></img>
      </div>
      <div className="Person-name">
        {capitalizeFirstLetter(data[length].name)}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Person;
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do, but you want to use a prop

Comment: I don't think I follow your question, but if you need to be able to send the `Button` state to `Person`, you should set up a `useState` variable, the state would go to `Person` and `set` function needs to be passed to `Button`, probably within a function to handle whatever button logic you have, and that function would be called on the button `onClick`

Comment: i need to send the button status to the statusCheck function, which will be the onClick for both buttons